# Compare URLs using PHP

Tags: php, url, compare, string-comparison

I have the following 3 urls

`http://www.yahoo.co.uk` and `http://yahoo.co.uk`, the difference being that the later doesn't have `www` in it. When using parse_url on both these url's, the output is the following.

`{"scheme":"http","host":"www.yahoo.co.uk"}`

`{"scheme":"http","host":"yahoo.co.uk"}`

Both url's being the same, comparing them using a `==` or using `strpos` or explode the text with `.` and compare each array doesn't seem to be ideal.

I have looked at the other questions on Stack Overflow that discusses about comparing URL's but they don't seem to be addressing the issue I have mentioned above. Appreciate if someone could help me figure out how to solve this issue.

Comment: does it matter if there's anything after the domain? such as `/index/?module=blah`?

Comment: The URLs are not the same. There's no rule that says that `www.DOMAIN` has to be the same as `DOMAIN`, although it usually is.

Comment: Actually, there are 2 different domains. Try to cut off the "www" part  and then compare what you have to compare there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple helper functions:

```
function compareUrls($a, $b) {
    $a = parse_url($a, PHP_URL_HOST);
    $b = parse_url($b, PHP_URL_HOST);

    return trimWord($a) === trimWord($b);
}

function trimWord($str) {
    if (stripos($str, 'www.') === 0) {
        return substr($str, 4);
    }
    return $str;
}

var_dump(compareUrls('http://www.yahoo.co.uk', 'http://yahoo.co.uk'));
```

Outputs:

```
bool(true)
```